# Linguagem C - Ler Ficheiro para gravar em Listas

Tags: c

Imaginem uma escola com várias salas, e cada sala tem varios alunos

Estou com dificuldades em ler ficheiro com o nome da sala, numero de lugares por filas(linhas e colunas)
Tenho a seguinte estrutura!

```
typedef struct
{
    char nome[50];
    int numero;
}Aluno;

typedef struct nodo{
    Aluno dados;
    struct nodo *anterior;
    struct nodo *seguinte;
}Nodo;

typedef struct{
    char sala[50];
    int linhas, colunas;
    Nodo inicio;
} Lista;
```

E o seguinte para ler do ficheiro, mas sei que está mal

```
int LerFicheiro(char *nf)
{
    FILE* w=fopen(nf, "r");
    Lista* li;

    int l,c;
    while (!feof(w))
    {
        fread(&li->nome, sizeof(Lista), 1, w);  // nome da sala
        fread(&li->linhas, sizeof(Lista), 1, w); //  nº linhas
        fread(&li->colunas, sizeof(Lista), 1, w);  // nº colunas

        for (l = 0; l <= li->linhas; l++)
        {
            for (c = 0; c < li->colunas; c++)
            {
                /*LER NOMES E NUMEROS*/


            }
        }
    }
    fclose(w);

}
```

Este é o ficheiro para ler!
Tem o nome da sala, na linha seguinte o numero de lugares em linha e em coluna!!! De seguida é tem o numero do aluno e nome do respetivo aluno

```
Sala de Historia
8 5
1231 
Joao Afonso
563
Zé Alves
7634
Rita Pereira
948
Patricia Mendes
39
Rui Santos
```

Alguém me consegue fazer ou ajudar nisto?

Muito Obrigado!!!!

Answer (score 0):

fscanf(f, "%d", &Imag->NLINHAS);

Normalmente eu costumo usar o "fscanf" em vez do "fread" para ler o conteúdo do ficheiro.

```
    fscanf(f,"%s" ,&li->titulo);  // nome da imagem
    fscanf(f,"%d",&li->linhas); //  nº linhas
    fscanf(f,"%d",&li->colunas);  // nº colunas
    fscanf(f,"%d",&li->canais);  // nº canais
```

As estruturas que colocaste são relativas à sala, mas o código para ler ficheiro é relativo a uma imagem, não te enganaste??? 
De qualquer modo, tens ainda de definir na estrutura Lista o título e os canais, sendo que queres essas variáveis no ler ficheiro.

```
typedef struct{
char sala[50];
char titulo[50];
int linhas, colunas,canais;
Nodo inicio;
} Lista;
```

Comment: Sim, erro meu, ja editei!!

Comment: nesse caso podes usar na mesma o que te mandei anteriormente, mas substituis as variáveis que tinhas, pelas novas (nome, linhas, colunas)

Comment: Mas, como vou fazer com as salas? a minha duvida é mesmo essa, ler sala a sala os lugares com os alunos

Comment: Como é que tens escrito no ficheiro? consegues mandar print de como está o ficheiro? assim é mais fácil para perceber como te hei de ajudar